# Converting a serialized array to a PSQL array, error

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm trying to do a migration that takes an existing column, which is a serialized array(text), and convert it into a psql array. I've tried a great number of things but keep getting an error.

This is what my migration looks like:

```
 class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
      rename_column :table_things, :column, :old_column

      add_column :table_things, :column, :text, :array => true, null: false, :default => []

      TableThing.class_eval do
        serialize :old_column, Array
      end

      TableThing.reset_column_information

      TableThing.find_each{|tt|
        tt.column = tt.old_column
        tt.save!
      }
     TableThing.reset_column_information
       remove_column :table_things, :old_column
    end
```

and this is the stack trace:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:    ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:41:in `save!'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `block in save!'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:275:in `save!'
    /Users/username/code/work/Jobber/db/migrate/20140317215526_rename_addons.rb:15:in `block in up'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:26:in `each'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:26:in `block in find_each'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:76:in `find_in_batches'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:70:in `find_in_batches'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:25:in `find_each'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_each'
    /Users/username/code/work/Jobber/db/migrate/20140317215526_rename_addons.rb:13:in `up'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `exec_migration'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `block in migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:557:in `migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:713:in `migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:963:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `block in ddl_transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `within_new_transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1009:in `ddl_transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:962:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:924:in `block in migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `each'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `up'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:746:in `migrate'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong, or things I can try to fix my problem?

Comment: Please provide text of error with stack trace.

Comment: I apologize, give me a moment

Comment: I don't think that error message is going to help much, also, it happens after the add_column

Comment: Do you have some before_save callbacks on your model that may interfere?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/RecordNotSaved

Comment: Good thought, I'll look into that, thank you

Comment: You could switch to `tt.save` and see if there is anything interesting in `tt.errors`.

Comment: thanks, it wasn't callbacks causing the problem, I'll try that in a bit and get back to you

Comment: I take it back, the problem was callbacks, thanks for the help guys! Both of your suggestions were super useful! If one of you wants to submit an answer comprised of both comments I'd gladly accept it. (the race is on!)

Comment: @Donald Or post your own answer explaining the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from .save! to .save helped show better error messages, in the end the issue was with callbacks so changing from

```
  TableThing.find_each{|tt|
    tt.column = tt.old_column
    tt.save!
  }
```

to

```
  TableThing.find_each{|tt|
    tt.update_column(:column, tt.old_column)
  }
```

Resolved the issue.